# Como instalar y usar ggplo2

Tags: r

Cuando trato de hacerlo obtengo lo siguiente:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

> Installing package into
> ‘/Users/davidcademartorirosso/Library/R/4.0/library’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> trying URL 'https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/ggplot2_3.3.2.tgz'
> Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 4064530 bytes (3.9 MB)
> ==================================================
> downloaded 3.9 MB
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> /var/folders/_b/3dymjpb13838xmwz9mzrxc_40000gn/T//RtmpCHn5N2/downloaded_packages

Despues cuando uso la funcion library obtengo lo siguiente:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in
> loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘vctrs’ In addition: Warning
> message: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.0.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no cuentas con el paquete `vctrs` en tu pc. Esto debería solucionar tu problema:

```r
install.packages("vctrs")
```